# is $\ c= \big( \overline{x+yi} \big)^2 \ $ equivalent to $ \ \overline{c^{1/2}}=x+yi $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

is $\ c= \bigg( \overline{x+yi} \bigg)^2 \ $ equivalent to $ \ \overline{c^{1/2}}=x+yi $?

EDIT

$c$ is complex, **but not real**.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Clayton  any counterexample?

Comment: @Clayton Does one at least imply the other?

Comment: Do you mean $x+iy?$  Where do you get the minus sign?

Comment: What do you mean by $c^{1/2}$?  That has two different possible values for most $c$...

Comment: @EricWofsey   I think I get it.  So statement 2 implies statement 1 but converse doesn't hold?

Comment: @saulspatz  yes.  corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=0, y=-1$. Then statement 1 becomes $c=-1$.

However, statement 2 becomes $ \ \overline{c^{1/2}}=i$. This is definitely not the same as the first statement, since $c=-1$. implies $ \ \overline{c^{1/2}}=-i $ or $i$. So it is a more general statement than statement 2.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add $c$ is not real.

Comment: I think I get it.  So statement 2 implies statement 1 but converse doesn't hold?

Comment: Not necessarily, I think. Since $$\overline{zw} = \bar{z} \bar{w}$$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. The second statement implies $\bar{c}$ is equal to the right side of statement 1.

Comment: Oh that was a typo..  corrected.  What about now?  s2 implies s1?

Comment: I see you've changed the question. I think s1 contains the case of s2, so s2 could be the result of s1, but you can't derives s1 solely from s2.

Answer (score 0):

You have $c=a+ib$, then $c^{\frac 12}=[r(\cos x+i \sin x)]^{\frac 12}$, where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $x=arctan(\frac{b}{a})$

Now by Moivre's formula

$c^{\frac 12}=
r^{\frac 12} \left[ \cos \left(
\dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )+i \sin 
\left( \dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )\right ],k=0,1$.

Finally when calculating the conjugate you will have to

$\overline{c^{\frac 12}}=
\overline{r^{\frac 12} \left[ \cos \left(
\dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )+i \sin 
\left( \dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )\right ]} ,k=0,1$.

$\overline{c^{\frac 12}}=
\overline{r^{\frac 12}} \overline{\left[ \cos \left(
\dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )+i \sin 
\left( \dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )\right ]} ,k=0,1$.

$\overline{c^{\frac 12}}=
r^{\frac 12} \overline{\left[ \cos \left(
\dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )+i \sin 
\left( \dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )\right ]} ,k=0,1$.

$\overline{c^{\frac 12}}=
r^{\frac 12} \left[ \cos \left(
\dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )-i \sin 
\left( \dfrac {x+2\pi k}{2}\right )\right ] ,k=0,1$.

On the other hand

$c=\overline{(x+iy)}^{2}=(x-iy)^2=x^2 -2ixy+i^2 y=x^2-y^2-2xyi$